# A view has already been added to the window manager

Tags: android, android-view, android-windowmanager

I have 2 views in my service and i want to switch them based on some situation. What i am doing to make a switching, remove first view and then add second view. Here is my code:

```
public void switchView(boolean toCallView) {
        if (toCallView) {
            if (lockScreenLayout != null && lockScreenLayout.getParent() != null && lockScreenLayout.getWindowToken() != null)
                windowManager.removeView(lockScreenLayout);
            if (callScreenLayout != null && callScreenLayout.getWindowToken() == null)
                windowManager.addView(callScreenLayout, layoutParams);
        } else {
            if (callScreenLayout != null && callScreenLayout.getParent() != null && callScreenLayout.getWindowToken() != null)
                windowManager.removeViewImmediate(callScreenLayout);
            if (lockScreenLayout != null && lockScreenLayout.getParent() != null && lockScreenLayout.getWindowToken() == null)
                windowManager.addView(lockScreenLayout, layoutParams); // exception raise here
        }
    }
```

But in some situation i still get application crash with following exception:

```
ACRA caught a RuntimeException for com.myapp
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=intent.activate.incoming.call.screen flg=0x10 (has extras) } in com.myapp.activity.LockScreenService$9@e94ff0a
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:895)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5524)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: View android.widget.RelativeLayout{d4d82ee V.E...... ......ID 0,0-720,1184} has already been added to the window manager.
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:281)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:86)
    at com.myapp.util.IncomingCallHandler.switchView(IncomingCallHandler.java:73)
    at com.myapp.activity.LockScreenService$9.onReceive(LockScreenService.java:270)
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:885)
    ... 7 more
```

Can someone give me hint how to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

As the exception states, the `lockScreenLayout` has already been added to the `WindowManager` and can not be added again. So you have two options to prevent this case:

**First**

Edit your logic. The case that some of your conditions are hitting twice should not occure

**Second**

Check if the view has already been added. Something like this:

```
if (!lockScreenLayout.isShown()) 
{
    // Add child to window
}
```

Comment: i understand you but I am not getting how i can check through WindowManager that view is already there or not OR is there some other way to check this info?

Comment: There is no method indexOfChild() in windowManager.

Comment: Ok...last edit. I don´t know what to do else, if this isn´t working.